# Hibernate 4.3.5 DetachedCriteria not fetching lazy list

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, detachedcriteria

I have a simple query that worked for a good time, now i changed some stuff in my code to:
(hibernate.cfg.xml)

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

and the following code:

```
public UserEn findByIDFetch(Long id, String... fetches) {
    beginTransaction();

    DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(UserEn.class);
    for (String fetch : fetches) {
        dc.createAlias(fetch, fetch, JoinType.INNER_JOIN);
    }

    dc.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));

    UserEn result = (UserEn) dc.getExecutableCriteria(getSession()).uniqueResult();
    commitTransaction();
    return result;
}
```

after the commit, result object don't have the list loaded (that is comming from `fetches`)
if i do `result.getAnyList().size();` before the commit, it keeps loaded, also, if i use `HQL` it works perfectly. (but it's not how it's supposed to work (let it open and load when used), createAlias should work fine as always)

It looks like DetachedCriteria's createAlias is not fetching the given path (in this case is `characterEnList`)

**@EDIT**
I found out that if i use `setFetchMode` in the desired path (`characterEnList` in this case) the fetching works but if i use `createAlias` (as usual) it simply stops working, i don't know how, probably a hibernate bug or something, anyway, i'll wait for someone answer, maybe someone that had the same problem...

Comment: Return the result to the service layer. In the same transaction access the list and hibernate should automatically populate the list for you.

Comment: the list is used only in the view, out of the transaction, the createAlias or setFetchMode was supposed to work (at least it did before using ThreadLocalSessionContext)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found as the same problem as follows: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7842
This is probably a bug, if i ask it to be inner join in the alias, it should be, i can do this with HQL, why can't i do with Criteria?

So, now i will have to use the `LEFT_OUTER_JOIN` type to solve this, or don't use alias at all (if i don't need to make a where clause or 2-depth fetch)

Hope it help someone, thanks for all your help!

**example**

```
dc.createAlias(fetch, fetch, JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
```

OR

```
dc.setFetchMode(fetch, FetchMode.JOIN);
```

Answer (score 0):

it is lazy loaded only when accessed during the transaction. So you must call the lazy loaded field during the transaction, for hibernate to fetch it. It will then be available in the view.

or of course make it eager.

Comment: well, if you `join fetch` it, you don't need to access to make it available, thats why it's called join fetch (like `HQL`), DetachedCriteria do the same, it always worked, it just stopped working for no reason, DetachedCriteria stopped loading the fetching aliases (always did it and always worked, just look at the question), main problem came after i started using `session context` as `thread` (`ThreadLocalSessionContext`)